# xml creation using java

Tags: java, xml

I want to iterate over a XML given below:

```
                <Annotation>
                    <Properties>
                        <PropertyValue PropertyName="field_label">label.modelSeriesCd</PropertyValue>
                        <PropertyValue PropertyName="ContainerType">conditionContainer</PropertyValue>
                    </Properties>
                </Annotation>
```

I am trying these codes:
1)

```
while(currentNode.hasChildNodes()){
                        System.out.println(currentNode.getNextSibling());
                        currentNode=currentNode.getNextSibling();
                    }
```

2)

```
for (int x = 0; x < childNode.getLength(); x++) {
                    Node current = childNode.item(x);
                    if (Node.ELEMENT_NODE == current.getNodeType()) {
                        String cN = current.getNodeName();
                        System.out.print(cN +" = ");
                        String cV = current.getNodeValue();
                        System.out.print(cV+" : ");
                        String cT = current.getTextContent();
                        System.out.println(cT);
                    }
                }
```

output:

```
[Shape: null]
ShapeType = null : H2
Annotation = null : 

                                label.modelSeriesCd
                                conditionContainer
```

I want output with all tag names and tag values i.e. it should display like:
Properties
PropertyValue
PropertyName "field_label"
value label.modelSeriesCd
means I want output with all tags ,attribute name, attribute values and text values.
so that I can write it in another XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method below recurse over an XML tree, printing the requested info:

```
public static void printNodeTree(Node n) {
    // print XML Element name:
    System.out.println("ELEM: " + n.getNodeName());

    // print XML Element attributes:
    NamedNodeMap attrs = n.getAttributes();
    if (attrs != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < attrs.getLength(); i++ ) {
            Node attr = attrs.item(i);
            System.out.println("ATTR: " + attr.getNodeName() + " = " + attr.getNodeValue());
        }
    }

    NodeList nodeList = n.getChildNodes();

    // print XML Element text value
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
        if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            String text = currentNode.getNodeValue();
            if (text != null && text.matches("\\S+")) {
                System.out.println("TEXT: " + text);
            }
        }
    }

    // recurse over child elements 
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
        if (currentNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            printNodeTree(currentNode);
        }
    }
}
```

You can initiate the traversal from the document root:

```
Document doc = ...
printNode(doc.getDocumentElement());
```

Output for the given input:

```
ELEM: Annotation
ELEM: Properties
ELEM: PropertyValue
ATTR: PropertyName = field_label
TEXT: label.modelSeriesCd
ELEM: PropertyValue
ATTR: PropertyName = ContainerType
TEXT: conditionContainer
```

Comment: I have posted a part of XML . I need to traverse from the required element and then I need to traverse within the node for it's child Nodes

Comment: printNodeTree() will accept any element, it doesn't have to be root. it wlil print all child elements under given arg

Comment: @ sharonbn please ssee my answer

Comment: you mean you completed your question with the code that doesn't work for you - hope you understand that is not an answer. you could edit your question.

Comment: i need to extract <tagname><attributes><tagvalues> so that I can write it in another XML but see the output it's not iterating deep upto the last child.

Comment: @ sharonbn I just want to iterate deep till last child node starting from a required node not from root node and want to extarct tagname, tagattribute and tagvalues as well

Comment: have you looked at my answer?? you need recursion to iterate deep and the posted code does that. it also contains comments on exactly how to get the desired info

Comment: if you need to get to a specific node within a tree, I suggest you use xpath. once you have the desired starting point, you can call printNodeTree() with the starting point

Comment: @ sharonbn I am able to reach to the specific node recursively but i am not able to traverse till the last child Node.

Comment: but my method contains a deep traversal of ALL tree under a given node - what are you missing ??